# Android : Hide RelativeLayout with animationwhen scroll down / up listview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-animation

I try to implement an animation for hiding a relativeLayout which is above a listview. I would like to have this behaviour :

- on Scroll DOWN: Hide RelativeLayout
- on Scroll UP : Show RelativeLayout only when i am at the top

[image]

The following code that i have created works, but there is 2 problems :

1. When i scroll down or when i scroll up, if i am at the top of the listview, there is a blink of the relativelayout. I must perform a fast scroll in order to hide this climb. => There is a problem in my code, maybe on listIsAtTop() function ?
2. And second problem, i don't have animation. I use setVisivility(VISIBLE or GONE) to show or hide the relativeLayout. It's not user friendly, isn't it ? :) I don't know how to add a little translation animation to hide and show this relativeLayout.

**in onCreate() of Account_Activity class :**

```
list = (com.app.frisbeee.account_view.CustomListView)findViewById(R.id.accountview_listview);
adapter = new Account_view_custom_adapter(Account_view_act.this, annoncesList);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            registerForContextMenu(list);

            list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    list.showContextMenuForChild(view);   
                }
            });

            list.setOnDetectScrollListener(new OnDetectScrollListener() {
                @Override
                public void onUpScrolling() {
                    /* do something */
                    Log.d("INFO", "UPPPPPPPPPPP");
                    if (listIsAtTop()) {
                        RelativeLayout relative1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative1);
                        relative1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onDownScrolling() {
                    /* do something */
                    Log.d("INFO", "DOWNNNNNNNN");
                    if (!listIsAtTop()) {
                        RelativeLayout relative1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative1);
                        relative1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                }
            });

        }
```

**Code of listIsAtTop function :**

```
private boolean listIsAtTop()   {   
        if (list.getChildCount() == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        return list.getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0 && (list.getChildCount() == 0 || list.getChildAt(0).getTop() == 0);
    }
```

**CustomListView** used to detect scroll UP and DOWN :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AbsListView;

public class CustomListView extends android.widget.ListView {

    private OnScrollListener onScrollListener;
    private OnDetectScrollListener onDetectScrollListener;

    public CustomListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        onCreate(context, null, null);
    }

    public CustomListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        onCreate(context, attrs, null);
    }

    public CustomListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        onCreate(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    private void onCreate(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, Integer defStyle) {
        setListeners();
    }

    private void setListeners() {
        super.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

            private int oldTop;
            private int oldFirstVisibleItem;

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
                if (onScrollListener != null) {
                    onScrollListener.onScrollStateChanged(view, scrollState);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                if (onScrollListener != null) {
                    onScrollListener.onScroll(view, firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount);
                }

                if (onDetectScrollListener != null) {
                    onDetectedListScroll(view, firstVisibleItem);
                }
            }

            private void onDetectedListScroll(AbsListView absListView, int firstVisibleItem) {
                View view = absListView.getChildAt(0);
                int top = (view == null) ? 0 : view.getTop();

                if (firstVisibleItem == oldFirstVisibleItem) {
                    if (top > oldTop) {
                        onDetectScrollListener.onUpScrolling();
                    } else if (top < oldTop) {
                        onDetectScrollListener.onDownScrolling();
                    }
                } else {
                    if (firstVisibleItem < oldFirstVisibleItem) {
                        onDetectScrollListener.onUpScrolling();
                    } else {
                        onDetectScrollListener.onDownScrolling();
                    }
                }

                oldTop = top;
                oldFirstVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnScrollListener(OnScrollListener onScrollListener) {
        this.onScrollListener = onScrollListener;
    }

    public void setOnDetectScrollListener(OnDetectScrollListener onDetectScrollListener) {
        this.onDetectScrollListener = onDetectScrollListener;
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me know once you achieve this. I too need the same. I had achieved the same in past by changing the `LayoutWeight` but very hacky.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this for the listIsAtTop() function:**

```
private boolean listIsAtTop()   {   
    if(listView.getChildCount() == 0) return true;
    return listView.getChildAt(0).getTop() == 0;
}
```

**As for the sliding animation:**

Code for slide_down.xml:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
    <translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:fromYDelta="-1000" android:duration="1500"/>
</set>
```

Code for slide_up.xml:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
    <translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:fromYDelta="1000" android:duration="1500"/>
</set>
```

Then load the animation in onCreate method:

```
Animation slideUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_up);
```

Then just attach it to your RelativeLayout:

```
relative1.startAnimation(slideUp);
```

Hopefully this helps :)

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't work verry well. Where i must put this line : `relative1.startAnimation(slideUp);` I try to put it just before setVisibility .. Have you tried your code ?

Comment: You put that line wherever you want your animation to execute. Yes I've tried this code, I use animations all the time :P Is the animation not working? What's happening when you run it?

Comment: I updated my code with yours, and make a little video of the problem. I hope that it will be more clear for you to understand why i am this problem of blinking... Here is the link : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5uiJlSSk9dZd2NBSmxWVGxPRk0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I see. Are you only applying the animation to the light pink part? Or are you applying it to the dark ping and grey bar too?

Comment: Only RelativeLayout with light pink. The purpose is to continue to show relativeLayout with dark pink during scrolling

Comment: Even without animation, i have the problem of blinking. In my log, i see that when i am a the top position "UPPPPPPPPPPP" and "DOWNNNN" logs are shown, which may be the cause of the blink. Maybe a problem in listIsAtTop function?

Comment: Alright. I think I have an idea of whats going on here. I ran into a similar problem with viewpagers (the blinking issue). I don't have the EXACT answer off the top of my head, but I can definitely point you in the right direction. Put some debug logs in all your scroll change / on scroll listeners, and when you get to the top of the list, check if it shows a flood of logs. Not just 1, but if you keep scroll up, I SUSPECT, you'll see 10-50 logs of the "top" message.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56733/discussion-between-jonny07-and-wawanopoulos).